# jQuery-Intellisense for passed Arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense

How can i achieve that I get jQuery-Intellisense in the following code example?

```
function doSomething($jQueryObject) {
    $jQueryObject.   // I want to have Intellisense here
};

var $parameter = jQuery('body');
doSomething($parameter);
```

The problem is that Intellisense doesn't know that the parameter for the function is a jQuery-Object. How could I tell the function the parameter type?

I know I could write in the function something like

```
$obj = $j($jQueryObject);
```

to create a new jQuery-Objekt, but I would like to know if there is another way to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a loosely typed language which means the type is not declared explicitely, but decided internally at runtime.

Interllisense **cannot** determine the type of the variables (whatever the editor) because it is simply not defined. You can pass whatever you want to your `doSomething()` method. This is a powerful and flexible way of programming. The *bad* side is that it might require implementing some checks to avoid errors/exceptions

If you are building some sort of framework or API for other developers to use, you should consider testing the parameters' type.

To test a jQuery typed variable, do this:

```
var $obj = $jQueryObject instanceof jQuery
              ? $jQueryObject
              : $($jQueryObject);
```

Note: prefixing the variable name with `$` is a good indicator of the jQuery nature of the expected variable for the developer using the function.

**Edit**: replaced `typeof === "jQuery"` by `instanceof jQuery`

Comment: Nope, framwork is not for external developer. Allright, then I have to create a new jQuery-Object. Thanks for your helpful answer!

Comment: By the way: `console.log(typeof $j('body'));` gives me `object` and not `jQuery`

Comment: My mistake, `instanceof` should be used and not `typeof`. Updated the answer.